# how to manipulate map value from different data

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Driver<Integer> driver  = new Driver<Integer>();

driver.add(30);
driver.add(31);
driver.add(32);
driver.add(33);
driver.add(34);
```

I have to query these drive in db again to get data like and stored in some custom data structres. another file act which is used i map2.

```
map.put(30,300);
map.put(31,311);
map.put(32,322);
map.put(32,333);
map.put(34,344);
```

I have one field attribute act if act like (1,2,3,4) and if act is greater then 1 minus with each element. when I minus the act then I got following output.

```
map2.put(29,300);
map2.put(30,311);
map2.put(31,322);
map2.put(31,333);
map2.put(32,344);
```

Now I have to map each map value with map2 value. as key are different so in map I am not able to get it. sorry for language problem.

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your last output and the last two rows need to be 32 and 33. On that note, why don't you just use `key+1` as your key?

Comment: Showing a complete program that anyone can run will compensate for your English skills and we will be able to help you more easily.

Comment: Your description is perfectly fine right up until the very end. Using concrete examples is a very good idea if you aren't sure about terminology.

Comment: Adding your program will help. If you already know that map2 keys will be one less than map1 keys.
You can compare both maps using this relation.

Comment: @Pramod I have dynamic value and I cant add 1 or minus, its just problem statement, minus is based on some business logic, can we get the value of map to map2 in some way.?

Comment: @R.deo, but in your question you said _I have to again query in db with -1 with each element,_

Comment: @Pramod I havve edited my question.

Comment: @ShanuGupta I have to get both value map and map2, before minus and after minus of each element. I have bulk of these type of entries.

Comment: You could get key for map2 from map1 keyset by subtracting 1 right?